# Will Upgrading to Paypal Pro break current implementation with PayPal Standard

Tags: paypal

My client wishes to keep customers within their site when making PayPal payments. I understand they need to upgrade to a PayPal Pro (or Advanced) account to achieve this. However, before I advise them to do this I want to be sure it won't break their existing website between now and when the new code is implemented.  Does anyone know if it is "safe" to upgrade from Standard to Pro without breaking the current implementation or should I advise they create a new account for the Pro integration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would not be any issues when upgrading from Website Payments Standard to PayPal Pro/Advanced.  You can still use standard and Express Checkout with PayPal Pro/Advanced.